# How to convert Text containing Images into pdf using iText#

Tags: c#, .net, image, text, itext

I have a richtextbox and by far, i have been successful in converting plain text into pdf using iTextsharp. Now, the situation is, when i copy some text from any source let's say a website and along text, it contains images. Now when i try to convert the content (text + images) into pdf, resulting pdf doesn't show images. I know that there would be some property to be set for the richtextbox or using itextsharp so to have images as well. I also know that we can insert images by giving path to that image but this is not what i want. I want to have plain text along with images while direct conversion from richtextbox to pdf. Forexample i have,![Im resulting pdf i want the same as in richtextbox][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts0ec.jpg

How can i have the same as in richtextbox? How can i specify orientation for text and image to be justified?

Comment: RTF support isn't actively being maintained in iText unfortunately so you won't find a lot of help. I would highly recommend finding a way to convert your RTF to HTML because the HTML support in the community is very strong. Here's one article that's talking about it: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e

Comment: Yeah i have already had a look at that but got no better experience. Well. By the way, thanks for your concern as i waited too long to have answers for that and you stood first in that. Applauded!